# View node.js api docs in IntelliJ Ultimate 12

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, intellij-idea

I am unable to get the node.js api documentation to appear in the documentation window/popup (ctrl+q) where the javadoc normally would be for a java project. For this code:

```
var http = require('http');
```

I can see the documentation for `require` in a popup...

[image: node.js require has documentation]

... but not for `http` ...

[image: node.js "http" modules has no documentation]

Interestingly, `http.` reveals correct auto-complete options with function signatures.

I am using:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 12.1.6
- Latest JetBrains NodeJS plugin (129.714)
- "Node.js v0.10.21 Core Modules" loaded as a library (from source tar.gz)

  - http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.21/api/ loaded as the documentation source
- Node.js v0.10.21 Core Modules, HTML, HTML 5 / EcmaScript 5, and Node.js Globals libraries on the root and all descendant files in the (two file) project.

I have read through [this official blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/03/attaching-the-sources-of-node-js-core-modules/) but not had any success. For reference I am trying to follow [the Node Beginner tutorial](http://www.nodebeginner.org/).

*Edit:* Ideally something like [the api doc's http entry](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.21/api/http.html#http_http) to appear in the popup.

Comment: Looks like http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1946.

Comment: @CrazyCoder that is definitely my issue, can't believe I did not see that in my search results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS integration has no support for the external documentation at the moment, please follow the [corresponding feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1946).